# How to call a method in the same class

Tags: java, methods

I am writing code for an e-mail system and I have one small problem, I can't figure out how to call a method.

what is the correct way to call the writeAllToFile method in the main method?

```
public class MailboxSystemSol{

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{
    //code is too long to post here
    }

    public static void writeAllToFile(Userlist ul, User u, Message me){
    //code is too long to post here
    }

}
```

Here is the UserList class:

```
/**
* Created by Broomhead0 on 4/11/14.
*/
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Userlist
{
    ArrayList<User> users;  //this is an arraylist that will store references to all users

    public Userlist()
    {

        users = new ArrayList<User>();
    }

    // find a user in the list based on the username
    public User findUser(String username)
    {
        // iterate through the array; only iterate according to how many users are currently in     the array
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++)
        {
            // access the particular user through users.(i), then get the name,
            // and call the equals method on that name to compare it with the input username
            if (users.get(i).userName.equals(username)){
                return users.get(i);
            }

        }
        // no user found
        return null;
    }

    // add a user to the list; only do so if the user does not yet exist
    public void addUser(User u)
    {
        if (findUser(u.userName) != null) //if there is a match,
            System.out.println("User already exists");
        else //if there is not match
        {
           users.add(u); //add the username
        }

    }
    //check if this is correct
    //accessors
    public User getUser(int i){
        return users.get(i);
    }

    public int getNumUsers(){
        return users.size();
    }


}
```

Here is the User class:

```
/**
 * Created by Broomhead0 on 4/11/14.
 */
public class User
{

    public String userName;  // the name of the user
    public Mailbox outbox; // reference to the mailbox of sent messages
    public Mailbox inbox;  // reference to the mailbox of received messages


    // create mailboxes according to the size given as input
    public User(String o, int boxsize) {
        userName = o;
        outbox = new Mailbox(boxsize);
        inbox = new Mailbox(boxsize);
    }

}
```

Here is the Message class:

/**
     * Created by Broomhead0 on 4/11/14.
     */

```
public class Message {

    // the properties of a message
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String subject;
    private String body;

    // all property values are known at creation of the message; so initialize
    public Message (String s, String r, String sub, String b)
    {
        sender = s;
        receiver = r;
        subject = sub;
        body = b;
    }

    // any nice format of printing the names and the values of the properties will do
    public void printMsg()
    {
        System.out.println("Sender: " + sender);
        System.out.println("Receiver: " + receiver);
        System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
        System.out.println("Message: " + body);
    }

    // what follows are basic getter methods

    public String getSender()
    {
        return sender;
    }

    public String getReceiver()
    {
        return receiver;
    }

    public String getSubject()
    {
        return subject;
    }

    public String getBody()
    {
        return body;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question begs the question -- what have you tried? How isn't it working for you? And where are you getting the UserList, User, and Message values that you pass in as arguments to the method?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, the UserList, User, and Message are other classes

Comment: `writeAllToFile(your_UL_argument, your_U_argument, your_ME_argument);`

Comment: It's a static method so you do not need to instantiate an object. You do not need to include the class name because you're calling it from the same class where it is defined.

Comment: @broomhead0: ***that's*** why I'm asking what those guys represent. Your question is ***very*** incomplete without more information about those classes. You're essentially asking us to guess what they represent and show how to use them without your telling us anything about them or showing us any code. Absurd.

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm still new, I'm trying to find a balance between adding too much code to the post and not enough, ill post them

Comment: Is that more reasonable now?

Comment: Somewhat. I assume that your question as originally posted is misleading. You already know in general how to call a static method within a static method as @WillNewton is showing you, correct? Your problem is with the **specifics** of your code above, how to call **this** method with the **correct** and meaningful parameters. If so, you will still have to figure out how to create your User, UserList and Message objects within your main method, and then pass them into your static method. If you are still stuck, you should re-work your question including changing the misleading parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MailboxSystemSol{

    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException{

        //define userlist, user and message variables..
        UserList userList = new UserList();
        User user = new User("Matthew", 1024);
        Message message = new Message("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@gmail.com", "Subject Content", "Body Content");

        //do something with declared variables...            

        writeAllToFile(userList, user, message);
    }

    public static void writeAllToFile(Userlist ul, User u, Message me){
        //code is too long to post here
    }

}
```